# Seems like some basics are missing from ubuntu...or I haven't set them up?

Tags: shell, command-line

I can't define a shell variable like so:

```
$a = "hello"
echo $a
echo a
$a
a
```

all lead to nothing. Also, this command doesn't work for me:

```
$ echo "HELLO HOW ARE YOU?" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

There's no output from this command. ]

So are these features not always available? Why wouldn't I have them in a recent plain-vanilla Ubuntu install?

Comment: try `a="hello"` (no $ when defining a shell variable, only when referencing it. For the command, what do "doesn't work" and "no output" mean? Do you get back to a prompt? what's the return value ($?)?

Comment: I just tried the second command, and I get `hello how are you?` What are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

You're on Ubuntu, so I'll assume you're using `bash`.

When you define a variable, you do it like this:

```
you@ubuntu:~$ a="hello"
```

No spaces. No dollar sign. It won't work otherwise.

You use the dollar sign whenever you want to use that variable you defined:

```
you@ubuntu:~$ echo $a
hello
```

Your third command should output the literal letter 'a':

```
you@ubuntu:~$ echo a
a
```

Your fourth command will do nothing *unless* you have something stored in variable `a`. If you properly stored the string "hello" in it, it'll do this:

```
you@ubuntu:~$ $a
bash: command not found: hello
```

Your fifth command is trying to run an executable called `a`, which doesn't exist. You'll probably be getting a message like the one in the last example.

As for the last command... Well, I'm getting this:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ echo "HELLO HOW ARE YOU?" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
hello how are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign variables with a dollar sign. Dollar signs are only used to read variables.

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) and [ExplainShell](http://www.explainshell.com/) are wonderful for debugging shell commands.